# Mounting a Samba share does work from Windows command line but not in Windows Explorer

Tags: windows, ubuntu, samba, network-share

I want to share a folder on our Ubuntu 20.04 Linux server to our Windows 10 Pro clients in the same network via Samba. So I installed Samba 4.11.6 on the server and created this (minimal) `smb.conf` configuration:

```
[global]
   workgroup = WORKGROUP
   server string = File server (Samba, Ubuntu)
   log file = /var/log/samba/log.%m
   max log size = 1000
   logging = file
   panic action = /usr/share/samba/panic-action %d
   security = user
   encrypt passwords = true
   passdb backend = tdbsam
   server role = standalone server
   obey pam restrictions = yes
   unix password sync = no
   passwd program = /usr/bin/passwd %u
   passwd chat = *Enter\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *Retype\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *password\supdated\ssuccessfully* .
   pam password change = yes
   map to guest = bad user
   usershare allow guests = no

[Data]
    comment = Data Share
    path = /data/Share
    read only = no
    browsable = yes
```

Then I created a Samba user for my existing user `mfb` on the Linux server:

```
sudo smbpasswd -a mfb
```

Then I (re-)started Samba:

```
sudo service smbd restart
```

Now I can correctly connect via `smbclient` from the server itself, and also mount that `Data` share on a Windows 10 machine using the command line:

```
net use D: \\LinuxServer\Data /PERSISTENT:YES
```

After providing `mfb` as user name and the new password from `smbpasswd` that `net use` command works fine, the Samba share is correctly mapped to drive `D:` on the Windows client.

However, there are two issues with this setup:

1. After rebooting the Windows client the share is not mounted any more, even though I have used the `/PERSISTENT:YES` switch; and
2. When I don't use the `net use` command on Windows, but instead want to map the network share directly from the Windows Explorer, providing alternative credentials (not my Windows user, but the `mfb` user from Linux/Samba), then it keeps asking me for the password (which works fine via `net use`).

Any ideas what I am missing here?

Comment: Don’t worry you are not the only one. For me, when done through explorer it crashes. And I think it is related to the fact nfs was the only thing installed during some time and not samba.